# How do I get my Cycles materials into blend4web?

Tags: blend4web

Just downloaded and installed blend4web.  Very nice tool.

Have a nicely textured model in Cycles, but when I export to .html it is all black.  No materials, no lighting.

Couldn't find beginner tutorial how to apply materials.  Could someone please describe what we need to do?

I hope it does not involve baking the textures.  Would like a simpler way.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: From blend4web faq: Why are materials for Cycles not supported? What should I do if I have a lot of such objects?
The Cycles renderer is not designed for work in real-time as it uses ray-tracing algorithms. Nevertheless, you can bake your Cycles materials into textures in order to use them in ordinary materials. On the other hand, Blend4Web supports shader nodes (aka node materials) which are fast enough in performance for real-time applications and at the same time make it possible to achieve a photo-realistic feel.

Comment: Thanks @LukeD.  I'm sorry I don't fully understand yet.  Does it mean I have to bake every object in the scene, and re-apply the materials in the blender4web render engine?  What exactly should I do to get my blend4web output looking the same (close as possible) to my Cycles renders?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Blender there is the Cycles render engine (non-real-time) and the GLSL viewport (real-time). Both has its own set of material nodes. Blend4Web is a real-time engine and thus leverages the viewport's nodes.

Comment: Thanks @Blend4Web.  Sounds like the answer is to learn Blender Internal materials and Blend4Web materials, in order to create real time renderable models for the internet.

Answer (score 1):

In Blend4web mode (not Cycles), make sure in the node editor window 'Use nodes' is not checked.

Create a new material, switch to the texture panel, click the checkered "Show other data textures" button and choose your image below.

[image]

Comment: Good news for Cycles users! Blend4Web is going to support some Cycles nodes in the upcoming release. Yay!

Comment: That's awesome news! Keep up the great work!